# Flexbox и проблема с display: flex

Tags: html, css

```css
`.about__items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.about__item {
  max-width: 360px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__items">
  <div class="about__item">
    <img src="img/about-1.png" alt="">
    <div class="about__item-title"></div>
    <div class="about__item-text"></div>
    <div class="about__item-btn">
      <a class="about__item-link" href="#"></a>
      <a data-fancybox data-src="#modal" href="javascript:;" class="default-btn"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что именно не работает у вас и какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: хочу чтобы елементы стали паралельно

Comment: посмотрите ответ ниже, нажав "выполнить код". Это то, что нужно?

Comment: нет, у меня так же и не работает

Comment: @MichaelBochko значит где-то ошибка :) В шапке опубликуйте html всего блока, который должен быть флексом.

Comment: вроде сделал. и у меня так три елемента

Comment: @MichaelBochko https://jsfiddle.net/adudnik/1badeku8/ вот я сделал на JSfiddle пример. 

Возможно дело в том, что вы не задаете flex:0 0 30%; для своих элементов. 

Подробнее об этом читайте тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: Все заработало. добавил родителю в display: inline-flex; спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста как между елементами добавить отступы?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.about__items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.about__item{
    max-width: 360px;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__items">
   <div class="about__item">item1</div>
   <div class="about__item">item2</div>
</div>
```